# Twitter Typeahead is is not showing suggestions in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, typeahead, searchkick

I have used elasticsearch with searchkick wrapper in my rails project. I have successfully integrated Twitter Typeahead (remote) into the project, but suggestions are not coming up. Can anybody Please look into this matter.

I am getting Response Back but typeahead is not showing it in suggestions.

**Pictures Below**

[image]

---

**Response**

[image]

**controller :**

```
def autocomplete
    render json: Product.search(params[:query], fuzziness: 10).map(&:name) 
end
```

---

**index.html.erb :**

```
    <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
  <ul>
    <li class="list">
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query],placeholder: "Search Here", class: "typeahead form-control", id: "product-search", autocomplete: "off" %>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary btn-size" %>
    </li>
      </ul>
<% end %>
```

---

**products.js**

```
 var names = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: '/products/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
  });

  // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
  names.initialize();

  // instantiate the typeahead UI
  $('#product-search').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: names.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: Actually I am quite beginner with Elasticsearch and Rails. Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, It worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not working with a typeahead lib, but i assume the problem here `displayKey: 'name'`, what's mean an `autocomplete` action in the `rails` should provide `json` with a key `name`, but you render an array. Try to remove `.map(&:name)` from `Product.search(params[:query], fuzziness: 10)`.